# Fastlane error: Unable to update my distribution certificates from custom Fastfile: match

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline, certificate, provisioning-profile, fastlane

I'm starting to have an issue with fastlane. When I run a custom Fastfile to generate my beta apps, app starts to compile but eventually terminates with an error. In the Fastlane / Jenkins  log I have:

```
[21:38:32]: [31mfastlane finished with errors[0m
[31m
[!] Your certificate '3TR1235JKQ.cer' is not valid, please check end date and renew it if necessary[0m
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE.
```

I have logged into the apple developer website. Gone into the provisioning profile and added myself. I have tried doing a project clean and downloading the certificates in Xcode but to no avail.

The Fastlane shows me I fetch certificates from git which is beyond my permission but the certificates in file format .p12 and .cer are saved to the target directory.

**Please tell me the workaround to resolve the error presented on  Fastlane / Jenkins log. Thank you in advance.**

Here is part of my fast file to download my certificates:

```
register_devices(devices_file: "./fastlane/devices.txt")
match(git_url: "https://abcc2004@bitbucket.org/demo/fastlane-cert.git",
  type:$buildType,
  app_identifier: ENV["APP_IDENTIFIER"],
  force_for_new_devices: true)
```